# Generating random numbers with a normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a dataset that looks, when charted, like this:
[image]

To me, this looks like a normal/gaussian distribution. The mean is 0.0017 and the standard deviation is 0.0571. I am trying to generate random numbers along the same distribution using numpy's np.random.normal function as follows:

```
a = numpy.random.normal(0.0017, 0.0571)
```

This creates results that look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the sloping of the distribution is much gentler, with a much smaller peak, and the outliers tail off much more quickly. Is there a way to adjust my standard distribution so that my randomly generated numbers match the originals more closely?

Comment: No -- this difference implies that your numbers do *not* come from a normal distribution! Calculate the [excess kurtosis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html) of your numbers and I suspect you will find that it is not zero (as it would be for a normal).

Comment: **To me**, the second one is the one that looks like a gaussian function (the actual bell curve). Your numbers distribute differently

Comment: Welsome to SO! As you can see, it is not obvious at all that your first data would be in a normal/gaussian distribution. Could you give us your arguments for thinking it is?

Comment: As of your initial data set, maybe you could get better shape agreement with a [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution). Use [scipy corresponding function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skellam.html) to generate it. You could give your input data in your question.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe you are correct. I was working with a long dormant memory of what a normal distribution was and got this wrong. The kurtosis of this dataset is 8.7. I obviously need to go off and learn a bunch of stuff. Can anyone help my by giving me an idea of what my data set looks like? Am I best of investigating "standard distribution with high kurtosis" or is there a better descriptor?

Comment: Even if it is gaussian (and I would start with mean=0), your std.dev (sigma) is NOT .0571. You could quickly estimate sigma from FWHM, sigma = FWHM/2.36. Max is at 1000, so half max is 500, at 500 you have FWHM ca 0.047, and sigma~0.02, that is your stddev to sample

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux It might help to explain that FWHM is [Full-Width-at-Half-Maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum).

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like a [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).  You can generate it using [numpy.random.laplace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.laplace.html).  I'd leave the default mean as zero, and estimate the scale parameter as the average absolute deviation from zero.  A quick and dirty scale approximation would be `standard-deviation / sqrt(2)`, since you already have an estimate of `s`, but I haven't checked (nor have I the time right now) whether that's biased.